# Fetch odd position value from array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I am trying to get only odd position in array but unable to do so.I am in short span of time .Can anyone tell me what can i do

```
data.each_with_index{|i,index| p i if index.odd?}

[ "shivam" "1" "2" "1", "", "2" "1", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
  [ "aman", "2", "5", "3", "3", "3", "2", "", "", "", "", "", ""]

["praneet", "1", "1", "1", "8", "1", "6", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
```

When I am trying to access bizs[0] it is giving me

```
dddddddtitle
dddddddtitle
dddddddtitle
dddddddtitle
dddddddtitle
dddddddtitle
dddddddtitle
dddddddtitle
dddddddtitle
dddddddtitle
dddddddtitle
dddddddtitle
dddddddtitle
```

and when I am trying to access biz[1] it is giving me this

```
dddddddaniket
dddddddshivam
dddddddtiwari
dddddddaman
dddddddverma
dddddddpraneet
dddddddsodhi
```

The output I am getting after this is

```
ddddddd["title", "aniket", "month1", "200", "month2", "200", "month3", "200", "month4", "200", "month5", "200", "month6", "200", "month7", "", "month8", "", "month9", "", "month10", "", "month11", "", "month12", ""]
ddddddd["title", "shivam", "month1", "1", "month2", "2", "month3", "1", "month4", "", "month5", "2", "month6", "1", "month7", "", "month8", "", "month9", "", "month10", "", "month11", "", "month12", ""]
ddddddd["title", "tiwari", "month1", "1", "month2", "4", "month3", "2", "month4", "2", "month5", "2", "month6", "1", "month7", "", "month8", "", "month9", "", "month10", "", "month11", "", "month12", ""]
ddddddd["title", "aman", "month1", "2", "month2", "5", "month3", "3", "month4", "3", "month5", "3", "month6", "2", "month7", "", "month8", "", "month9", "", "month10", "", "month11", "", "month12", ""]
ddddddd["title", "verma", "month1", "3", "month2", "6", "month3", "4", "month4", "5", "month5", "3", "month6", "3", "month7", "", "month8", "", "month9", "", "month10", "", "month11", "", "month12", ""]
ddddddd["title", "praneet", "month1", "1", "month2", "1", "month3", "1", "month4", "8", "month5", "1", "month6", "6", "month7", "", "month8", "", "month9", "", "month10", "", "month11", "", "month12", ""]
ddddddd["title", "sodhi", "month1", "1", "month2", "", "month3", "1", "month4", "", "month5", "4", "month6", "", "month7", "", "month8", "", "month9", "", "month10", "", "month11", "", "month12", ""]
```

Now All I have to do is just ignore odd position values and store in a new array 
Final output should be like this

```
[ "aniket",  "200",  "200", "200", "200", "200", "200", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
     [ "shivam" "1" "2" "1", "", "2" "1", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
     [ "tiwari", "1", "4", "2", "2", "2", "1", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
     [ "aman", "2", "5", "3", "3", "3", "2", "", "", "", "", "", ""]

     [ "verma", "3", "6", "4", "5", "3", "3", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
     ["praneet", "1", "1", "1", "8", "1", "6", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
     ["sodhi", "1", "", "1", "", "4", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
```

I am unable to do so Can anyone help me out with this???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one works

```
bizs.select.with_index { |_, index| index.odd? }
```

**irb output**

```
bizs = ["title", "aniket", "month1", "200", "month2", "200", "month3", "200", "month4", "200", "month5", "200", "month6", "200", "month7", "", "month8", "", "month9", "", "month10", "", "month11", "", "month12", ""]

bizs.select.with_index { |_, index| index.odd? }
#=> ["aniket", "200", "200", "200", "200", "200", "200", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
```

Comment: Nishtha, consider waiting quite a bit longer before selecting an answer. You should select the answer you find most helpful, not the first one that is acceptable. A quick selection--and this one was very quick--may discourage other answers and imo is discourteous to those still preparing answers. You may have felt pressured to accept this answer because Deepak instructed you to do so. He had no business doing that, and he certainly wouldn't have told a SO veteran to do that, for he knows it would have fallen on deaf ears or produced a scathing retort. Most here wait at least a couple of hours.

Answer (score 0):

`result = []
array.each_with_index{|i,index| result << i if index.odd?}`

Comment: not working let me show you my output after doing this

Comment: you can use `array.each_with_index.with_object([]){|(i,index), result| result << i if index.odd?}`

Answer (score 0):

Please find my proposed code as shown below,

```
even_items = []
odd_items  = []

data.each_with_index do |bizs, index|
  if index % 2 == 1
    odd_items  << bizs[index]
  else
    even_items << bizs[index]
  end
end
```

This will result in two arrays one inserting all the elements with an odd index in **odd_items** array and the inserting all the even elements in the **even_items** array.